# Salt-stack target minion with argument and script

Tags: salt-stack

Start of script looks like this:

```
salt-key -L >/path/minions  
SERVER=`shuf -n 1 /path/minions`  
salt -C $SERVER file.write /tmp/salt_eicar.sh args='X5O!P%#
```

and so on...

This works fine. No problem.

This does not work:

```
salt -C '$SERVER and not G@os:Windows' file.write /tmp/salt_eicar.sh args='X5O!P%....
```

But above line works fine in prompt with a minion name instead of $SERVER. So something with a variable inside -C I suppose?

Answer (score 1):

It's a shell issue. You should use double quotes `"` to allow bash to expand the variable `$SERVER`.

```
salt -C "$SERVER and not G@os:Windows" file.write /tmp/salt_eicar.sh args='X5O!P%....
```

Comment: "Avoid +1 and thanks"... hm.. thanks anyway :)